# Determine a limit of a product

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

I would like to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)(1+f(x))^{2x}=0
$$

Is this trivial because
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)(1+f(x))^{2x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}((1+f(x))^{2x})
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}((1+f(x))^{2x})=\underbrace{\overbrace{\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+f(x))}^{=1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\overbrace{\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+f(x))}^{=1}}_{2x-times}=1
$$

I think this is not valid since as $x\to\infty$, the number of factors goes to infinity.

Comment: No you're wrong! Here, $2x$ is infinity and you can't just use infinity as a number. For getting more about what I'm saying note that $e=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ but you can't just write it infinite times and say each of them are 1.

Comment: Hint: consider $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$.

Then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{-1/2}(1+x^{-1/2})^{2x}=\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{-1}(1+t^{-1})^{2t^2}=\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{-1}((1+t^{-1})^t)^{2t}.$$

The last expression is bounded below by $\dfrac{2^{2t}}t$ (for $t\ge1$) and the limit diverges.

---

Note that with $f(x)=x^{-1}$ you bound above with $\dfrac9x$ and the limit is indeed $0$. It is much more challenging (though IMO possible) to find a function that leads to a finite limit.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your interpretation of $(1+f(x))^{2x}$.

- When $x$ is a real number, the expression $a^x$ ($a>0, a\ne 1$) is not interpreted as the multiplication of "$x$ many $a$'s". It does not make sense to say multiply $\pi$ copies of $a$. Instead, one of its definitions is
  $$
  a^x=e^{x\ln a}
  $$
- Even you restrict $x$ to be positive integers,
  $$
  \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^{n}\ne \lim_{n\to\infty}(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n)^{n}.
  $$

---

The statement you want to show:

> if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)(1+f(x))^{2x}=0$

is in general **not true**. The problem is that one of the factor is of the [indeterminant form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form): $1^\infty$. One counterexample has been given in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010971/determine-a-limit-of-a-product/4010978#comment8278894_4010971) and Yves's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4010995/).

As a convenient sufficient condition, if the function $f$ is in addition such that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln((1+f(x))=0
$$
then by continuity, you have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\big(2x\ln((1+f(x))\big)=1
$$

Comment: You would have to prove that $2x \log(1 + f(x)) \rightarrow 0$. And that is not trivial.

Comment: But then your answer is not complete. But  I guess you only wanted to give a hint...

Comment: as in it is not wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I kind of misread

Comment: @Meowdog: I didn't read your comment carefully. I apologize for my wrong interpretation of the question. I was assuming that OP's original statement is correct. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I apologize, too.

Comment: @Meowdog: one silly thing I did is I was thinking $f(x)\ln(1+f(x))\to0$, instead of $x\ln(1+f(x))$...